# Yolov3 - Concatenate output layers to speed up training

Tags: pytorch, yolo

I am using Yolov3 in Pytorch and have got 5 classes. Each class consists of approx. 500 images and after 2.500 iterations I get an mAP of 0.80%. However, the training takes approx. 2 days and I am strongly wondering how to decrease the training time.

One idea is to take a pretrained yolov3 network weights file, concatenate the three output layers and use these layers for training.

What do you think of this idea? Or will this not work?

Thanks!

Comment: Yolo3 in PyTorch. How does your model look like. Can you share the link.